# Kafka Stream to sort messages based on timestamp key in json message

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am publishing Kafka with JSON messages, eg:

```
"UserID":111,"UpdateTime":06-13-2018 12:13:43.200Z,"Comments":2,"Like":10
"UserID":111,"UpdateTime":06-13-2018 12:13:40.200Z,"Comments":0,"Like":6
"UserID":222,"UpdateTime":06-13-2018 12:13:43.200Z,"Comments":1,"Like":10
"UserID":111,"UpdateTime":06-13-2018 12:13:44.600Z,"Comments":3,"Like":12
```

I would like to sort messages based on `UpdateTime` in 10 second time window using Kafka Streams and push back sorted messages in another Kafka topic.
I have created a stream, which reads data from the input topic and then I am creating `TimeWindowedKStream` after `groupByKey()` where the UserID is the key in the message (Although its not necessary to `groupByKey` and then sort, but I could not get `WindowedBy` directly). But I am not able to sort messages in 10 second window based on `UpdateTime` further. My source code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-sorting");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "broker");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream("UnsortedMessages");
        TimeWindowedKStream<String, String> countss = source.groupByKey().windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(10000L)
                 .until(10000L));
        /*
        SORTING CODE
            */
        outputMessage.toStream().to("SortedMessages", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        // attach shutdown handler to catch control-c
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("streams-sorting-shutdown-hook") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                streams.close();
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
        try {
            streams.start();
            latch.await();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort messages ignoring the key, it makes only sense to do this based on partitions and also only if the input topic has the same number of partitions as the output topic. For this case, you should extract the partition number and use it as message key (cf: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#accessing-record-metadata-such-as-topic-partition-and-offset-information)

For sorting, it's more tricky. Note, that Kafka Streams follows a "continuous output" model and does emit updates for each input record using the DSL. Thus, it might be better to use Processor API. You would use a `Processor` with an attached store and put records into the store. As an in-memory structure you keep a sorted list of records. While time advances, you can emit "finished" windows and delete the corresponding records from the store.

I don't think you can build this using the DSL.

Comment: Sketched up an example here: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/issues/179